# Find the current position of MFC Dialog

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a mode-less MFC Dialog which when closed and re-opened, I want the window to appear on the same spot that it was closed on. To do this I need the x,y co-ordinates of the window before it closes (so i can save them in variables and apply them on to the setWindowsPos() of the new window).

How can I find the current position co-ordinates of the Dialog? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Google is your friend So please search on google before posting here.https://www.google.co.in/#q=get+current+position+of+mfc+dialog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RECT rect;
::GetWindowRect(GetSafeHwnd(), &rect);
```

This will return you the position.

MFC-ish Version :)

```
RECT rect;
CWnd::GetWindowRect(&rect);
```

Comment: Since the question is tagged "MFC", I think using CWnd::GetWindowRect() is better. At least, more "MFC-ish"

Answer (score 2):

Try using GetWindowPlacement
Here is a link to the documentation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633518(v=vs.85).aspx